# Receiving 404 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T]

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, azure-storage

In our application, we used to upload an HTML document at Azure file storage.
It was happening successfully until[14-May-2019]. Right now we are receiving 404 error intermittently. The error says

```
WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFile.<PutRangeImpl>b__53(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\File\CloudFile.cs:line 4820
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-nov17\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 299
```

Whereas on retrying, the files are getting uploaded successfully.

The Azure storage library we are using is Version 9.2.0.0.

Following code is used to upload the files.

Any thoughts on what could have triggered this issue would be helpful

```
 var file = await GetCloudFile(fileId);
            await file.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently [max size of a block blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits) is approx. 4.75 TB, storing MB-sized data in a block blob, which should not cause Azure Blob service return [404](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes) when you access the blob. 404 error indicates that the specified blob does not exist, Blob name is case-sensitive, please make sure the filename (blob name) you provided indeed exists in your container.(Also case sensitivity in terms of file extension like jpeg, JPG)

Also for clear troubleshoot, see `RequestInformation` inside `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException` which is thrown from Upload[xxx]Async methods for more detailed information.

Hope it helps.